# Consistent notation in multivariate statistics

Tags: statistics, notation

I'm reading [The Elements of Statistical Learning](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/). In the process I found myself lost in the notation, so I'm trying to get one that's as explicit and pedantic as possible:

$X$, $Y$: continous random variables

$p_{X,Y}(x,y): $ joint probability distribution of $x$ and $y$

$p_X(x):$ marginalized distribution for $x$

$p_{Y\mid X}(x\mid y):$ conditional distribution of $y$ given $x$

This gives us the following notation of Bayes' Theorem:

$$\underbrace{p_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) \cdot p_Y(y)}_{p_{X,Y}(x,y)} = \underbrace{p_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) \cdot p_X(x)}_{p_{X,Y}(x,y)}$$

using this, marginalization looks like this:

$$p_X(x) = \int_Y p_{X,Y}(x,y)\cdot dy = \int_Y p_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) \cdot p_Y(y) \cdot dy$$

Given a function $h(x,y)$, we can define expected values as:

$$E_{X}[h(X,Y)] := \int_X h(x,y) \cdot p_X(x) \cdot dx$$

$$E_{Y\mid X}[h(X,Y)] := \int_Y h(x,y) \cdot p_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) \cdot dy$$

$$E_{X,Y}[h(X,Y)] := \int_X \left(\int_Y h(x,y) \cdot p_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) \cdot dy\right) \cdot dx$$

This allows us to write the law of total expectation as follows:

$$E_{X,Y}[h(X,Y)] = E_X[E_{Y\mid X}[h(X,Y)]]$$

Writing the expected value of a sum of looks as follows:

$$E_{X,Y}[X + Y] = E_X[X] + E_Y[Y]$$

So, the subscript of E tells us, over which variable and which distribution to integrate.

So far so good, the notation is quite cumbersome, but it's consistent. I run into a problem when trying to do the following:

Assume

- $y = f(x) + \epsilon$

We then  to compute the expected squared prediction error of $E_{X,Y}[(\hat f(X)-Y)^2]$ of a predictor $\hat f$. Along the way (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias-variance_tradeoff#Derivation)) we get a term $E_{X,Y}[(Y-f(X))^2]$, which according to the above definition is $E_{X,Y}[\epsilon^2]$.

Now how do I know this is equal to $E_\epsilon[\epsilon^2]$?

Comment: The subscripts on $E$ serve no purpose and should not be used.  The subscripts on $f$ and $F$ are essential. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: . . . and note the proper use of \mid in MathJax and LaTeX.  See my edits to the question. The notation that was there before does not result in proper spacing.  \mid provides spacing when expressions are on both sides of it, that does not appear when something is on only one side.

Comment: \mid noted, thanks. =)

Comment: I like the way the subscripts in $E[]$ make it explicit what you're integrating over. In the text book above you don't have them and to me it's never quite clear what the underlying integral looks like. How do you know which of the above you mean when you omit the subscripts?